How to determine the shape of each triangle? Are they an acute, right-angled, or obtuse triangles?
Given the coordinates of the three vertices of multiple triangles in a list, how can we determine at once whether each triangle is acute, obtuse, or right-angled?
How can we determine the shape of each triangle based on the coordinates of the three vertices of multiple triangles in a list? Are they acute triangles, right-angled triangles, or obtuse triangles?

I tried to solve the problem myself, and I can determine whether a given triangle is a right-angled triangle, an acute triangle, or an obtuse triangle based on its three vertex coordinates. The code is as follows:
triangles = Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}}]
innerAngle = PolygonAngle[triangles] // FullSimplify
maxAngle = Max[innerAngle]
If[maxAngle > \[Pi]/2, "Obtuse triangle", 
 If[maxAngle == \[Pi]/2, "Right triangle", "Acute triangle"]]
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], triangles}]



However, if the coordinates of the three vertices of multiple triangles are given in a list form, how can we identify the type of each triangle at once? such as:
vertexcoordinateslist = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 
    0}, {8, 7}}, {{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{2, 9}, {8, 17}, {15, 
    0}}, {{-2, 10}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{10, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 
    5}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {6, 7}}}



See this question

@ubpdqn Of course, that's not the same question. The post you mentioned is about determining whether three points can form a triangle. My question is, given the coordinates of the three vertices of a triangle, how to determine the type of triangle—whether it is a right-angled triangle, an acute triangle, or an obtuse triangle.

Isn't this exactly the same question you asked yesterday? Atre you serious? (-1)

“if the coordinates of the three vertices of multiple triangles are given in a list form, how can we identify the type of each triangle at once?” So, again, you copy the code in your previous question from somewhere without understanding it, and after asking 247 undeleted questions, you don't even bother to learn the usage of /@, right?

I may have referenced wrong question but believe is duplicate.

@xzczd, It is not the same question since every triangle on that question was a right-angled triangle.

@Syed But OP clearly asks "how can one identify whether the triangle is an acute triangle, a right triangle, or an obtuse triangle" in that question. A different data set won't make this question a different question.

@Syed And thanks for reminding me, I didn't notice OP is again pretending that (s)he has made effort with code that doesn't make sense in previous question (probably generated with things like ChatGPT).

@xzczd You have given this user good advice many times. I hope they start incorporating.

triangles = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 
    7}}, {{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{2, 9}, {8, 17}, {15, 
    0}}, {{-2, 10}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{10, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 
    5}}, {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {6, 7}}}
maxAngles = Max /@ PolygonAngle /@ Polygon /@ triangles;
triangleTypes = 
 If[# == Pi/2, "Right Triangle", 
    If[# < Pi/2, "Acute Triangle", "Obtuse Triangle"]] & /@ maxAngles

which returns:

{"Obtuse Triangle", "Right Triangle", "Right Triangle", "Acute 
Triangle", "Obtuse Triangle", "Obtuse Triangle", "Acute Triangle"}

